# Python: how to scrape an AJAX website with requests

Tags: python, web-scraping, python-requests, urllib

So i found an [XHR call](https://prematch.planetwin365.it/api/mobileapp/v1.0/events/subevents/7/1?eventIds=7882&marketId=1) that contains the data that i want to scrape from a [website](https://m.planetwin365.it/it/scommesse/selezionemultipla/calcio/italia/italia-serie-a/7882). I read from multiple stack overflow posts that after finding the AJAX call you just need to make a simple request and get the data out of it.
I tried doing so with this script:

```
import requests

url = 'https://prematch.planetwin365.it/api/mobileapp/v1.0/events/subevents/7/1?eventIds=7882&marketId=1' 
resp = requests.get(url) # tried switching to requests.post(url) without results
print(resp.text)
```

But the code just hang there and never terminates with an output.
I also tried switching to urllib module but nothing changed.

I'll include in the post the parameters of the XHR call:

[image]

[image]

Comment: first you should use `DevTools` in `Firefox`/`Chrom`e to see all details when page runs this `XHR` call. Some servers check if request has header `x-requested-with`, others check header `User-Agent`, others check also `cookies` and header `referer`. Others may add some special header - ie. with API_KEY. So you would have to check all these elements.

Comment: you should show url of page which sends this `XHR`. And then we can test this page in web browser and use `DevTools` to see what values it sends - `cookies`, `headers`, `body`. We can't get this informations using only url to XHR call.

Comment: @furas thank you for your recommendations, i'm going to edit the post to add the link and also try to check those parameters by myself to see if i can understand what i'm missing.

Comment: when I open your link then I see `"Access denied to planetwin365"` so I can't help you

Comment: @furas i included some screenshots of the XHR call, i'd really appreciate if you could help me or link me a source to learn more about this, because i honestly don't know where to start.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After some time i eventually found the way to make the script work, i just needed to add the cookies and their values to the request.

```
import requests

url = 'https://prematch.planetwin365.it/api/mobileapp/v1.0/events/subevents/7/1?eventIds=7882&marketId=1'
cookies = {
    '_abck': '9E74104BD81F74BC1F7FE4F350725782~-1~YAAQBn16XKY4SGV/AQAAiyhkcAeyPf4pbo56aNcfqyMn8VMbBaeceOur9oNhuYnoPqJLsjnAoocCbDKkgZFOEWoiwlfNk6V6Udj4P/70hBovYJi2DKCMZB9HBGinWe9zrW2SsT3DbYtXQsRmavMP2j6peUAaz0szRjJ7DL5TR/ykRMDUw6tIT5Shdnt92hpyD1ZAIiUaIK/zDF3uovwlL3fEVdCUDLAm31PLdD0jpoyykElqiq5Hoa+PLmUUDO3jpnksaOcufWNi3xpJY20Kv0381tW/ItRynw7Eb6HFArdBaQFwlAM02at0sE4aUQVP96LO8RM0yEZVxPMYqf0MjZO+QxmRzganJc0ZSCiosKQJxTPf3Yqc7Zty0NIcUE+Ehg==~-1~-1~-1',
    'ak_bmsc': '718C62489D4C3B70E59118960293A120~000000000000000000000000000000~YAAQBn16XKc4SGV/AQAAjChkcA/rBuRQOYpDBHKR8qBQYKUQ8qss5cHy1xWge/7l0CMUrerZbMcXsARKXQWby6r5KhTnRZdhUs9Y7ye2L41kULV0/AUk0scTAlFloaKEGCLQr0+JJX1s6xsl0NhwwoVRheIFGXNec3OGa1sKpIxDbmxdVDA13UE2ro0+FomMrb4Rha/KrchRq8SB6X891og4rS7BZAiNN99bTDjfXpadkOyx6BOP/K5YzWFGIFySyYO2rl5GM6+6yZZgYWFwf/QuwNulNjBJcJwL18R1JoXJhdsEsohMaxcWRA+k+JEH6KBf8tWzXnxD/W7Zziu1tYWlqgKLXn2YSY4xZRpgkW/3y/Nk3h3/SIWKkZW7QqcyRmEVcw==',
    'bm_sz': 'E2F27C0E90271F31FED908CFCF988112~YAAQBn16XKg4SGV/AQAAjChkcA9A84+G6l+xysXyS5accePwqGAtL3XIjfqODlfHfczD3DNN2/8D2d88HJd6tAtS54VEo96LvEgGNsRsnUJdGygSKLRreqzkoc68h7eO7UtqkX6EAJUM4haPybJHwTgl5u63yMusZB7JrDeBa9IVW32Ie671N7b0RIE9SWEuYO6DD7AVj6gv5mX3/GNHfygXiIPqXpcUyRiJkRf+/Uu5ryWYTGkAGsWChI8liZC4afObCk9lT2vhIZlvdagFPXJ2ADbVD3Mk8EFionnfFX3qWxiPMe+UqA==~4470852~4274480'
}

def main():
    response = requests.get(url, cookies=cookies) 
    return response.text

if __name__ == '__main__':
    print(main())
```

Comment: maybe you should use `requests.Session()` and first get main page - to get fresh cookies -  and later get this page and session will use cookies.

Comment: How can i get the cookies from the original website if it block my request? I suppose it does it for the same reason of the XHR request: cookies.

Comment: if it blocks you then it is too late to get cookies. If it block access some IP or countries then you may try to use some proxy server to have different IP or connect from different country.